# rails_admin - has_many association - default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

My Page model look like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blocks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blocks, allow_destroy: true

  rails_admin do
    edit do
      fields :title, :slug, :blocks
    end
  end
end
```

My Block model look like this:

```
class Block < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page

  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :title
      field :body, :ck_editor
    end
  end
end
```

I needed workflow like this:
As an admin I click create page and I should see opened new block section with prefield title.

[image]

How can I create this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

My own answer is realy dearty, but it works for me:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blocks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blocks, allow_destroy: true

  rails_admin do
    edit do
      fields :title, :slug
      field :blocks do
        # It is needed to show nested form
        active true
      end
    end
  end

  # It is needed to create default block with title "main"
  after_initialize do
    if self.blocks.empty? && self.new_record?
      self.blocks << Block.new(title: 'main')
    end
  end

  # It is needed to prevent create default block when form has errors
  after_validation do
    return if(self.persisted? || self.blocks.empty?)
    destroy_array = []
    self.blocks.each do |block|
      destroy_array << block if block.title == 'main' && block.body.nil?
    end
    self.blocks.destroy(destroy_array)
  end
end
```